# Create Google AMP for every page?

Tags: amp-html

I read guidelines in Google AMP and have 2 questions.

1. Does that mean I need to create duplicated Google AMP page for my entire website? Including landing page, Privacy page and not just content pages?
2. Do I need to create 404 page for Google AMP page as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you only need to create AMP pages for articles and other content that would benefit from it.

You don't need a separate 404 page for AMP purposes. Your regular 404 page should be fine. Google's AMP Cache CDN will see your 404 and respond appropriately, I'm sure.